# Standard template for certain library tags

Tags: feature-request

For certain libraries esp. Artificial Intelligence or Machine Learning related, it's quite important to know the following:

- Which model is the question about?
- Which dataset is the question about?
- What version of the library is in question?

There's quite a lot of questions that can be quickly solved or easier to answer if the above information is added in the question,

- [Predicting with model and trying to save at the same time gives different prediction results and doesnt save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75966325/predicting-with-model-and-trying-to-save-at-the-same-time-gives-different-predic)
- [Huggingface Transformers (PyTorch) - Custom training loop doubles speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75952444/huggingface-transformers-pytorch-custom-training-loop-doubles-speed)

Sometimes asker voluntarily gives the information:

- [Huggingface Transformers (PyTorch) - Custom training loop doubles speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75952444/huggingface-transformers-pytorch-custom-training-loop-doubles-speed)

But **is there some way other than just commenting on the question to suggest users to add those 3 bits of information before that?**

Comment: Do the tags usually used for these questions say that's what is needed?

Comment: Isn’t the MRE help page enough?

Answer (score 5):

Making a change to the system for something like this is generally not done. Historically, the need/desire for something like this has been handled by:

1. Adding a section in the Tag Wiki describing how to create a MCVE/MRE for debugging questions in the tag. A comment directing the question author to the Tag Wiki can then be placed on questions which are closed for needing debugging details where referencing it is seen as beneficial.
2. Posting a comment on the question closed as needing debugging details saying what is needed in an MCVE (e.g. my personal auto-comments contain such comments for some low-traffic tags which I've participated in where question askers typically leave out critical information).
3. Creating a "How to create a MCVE/MRE for X" question and answer pair here on Meta Stack Overflow. Someone can then then leave a comment pointing the question author to that Q&A on questions which are closed for needing debugging details where referencing it is seen as beneficial, and the MSO Q&A can be linked in the Tag Wiki. Such posts can be quite detailed and give substantial advice. Historically, some such posts were created on the main Stack Overflow site, but they belong here on Meta Stack Overflow, as they are definitely "meta" questions.